# unable to get value of i in for loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a simple for loop and it is matching condition according to my log files
but still the value of i is showing `undefined`

here is my javascript code

```
var indexs,i;
  for(i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++){
        if (new Date(data[0][i]) == new Date(inRecord.rdate))
        {indexs = i;
             }
    Logger.log(new Date(data[0][i])+ " : " +new Date(inRecord.rdate) +": indexes:"+indexs)
    }
```

and Image below if my log output which shows the condition should matched.

[image]

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Seems that `new Date(data[0][i]) == new Date(inRecord.rdate)` never is true

Comment: it looks like the `indexs = i;` is not being executed. can you add a `debugger` or `console.log` in there and check.

as @Jon said the condition is never true

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: I recommend you to compare them with the `getTime()` function as it return the amount of miliseconds from 1970 or something like that. Comparing numbers is safer. Log both of them and see if they are equal. One day i got with a problem that the `getTime()` was different even the day was identical. Your last option would be comparing the year AND month AND day. Good luck

Comment: Do you check `if (new Date(data[0][i]) == new Date(inRecord.rdate))` condition is true for the every iteration of **for-loop**. If not then `indexs` will never be reassigned value of `i`  and returns `undefined` in Logger.log output.

Comment: Please simplify: `const rdate = new Date(inRecord.rdate).getTime(); const items = data[0].filter((item,i) => new Date(item).getTime() === rdate)`

Comment: Strangely .getTime() fuction worked for me. thanks Jon

Comment: Equality with `==` and even `===` on Date's always return false as they are different objects even when they contain the exact same time. Either convert it to number via `Date.getTime()`: `date1.getTime()===date2.getTime()` or do that indirectly with some trick like `date2 - date1===0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new Date creates an object which cannot be compared. Even if two of these objects are identical, they will not produce a true comparison. To get around this, define them before the IF statement and compare the millsecond values with getTime(). This will be comparing two numbers (not objects) and work great :)

```js
let dataDate = new Date(data[0][i])
let recordDate = new Date(inRecord.rdate)
if (getTime(dataDate) == getTime(recordDate)) {
indexs = i;
}
```

Happy to clarify if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

new Date returns an object. And two objects can not be compared even where they contain the same data. The result will always be false.